# What's the word for 'reading multiple books from different perspectives to form your opinion'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember reading a word that means reading multiple books to form your opinion on a subject, but I forgot the word.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: It sounds like *research*.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for ***[versed](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/versed)***:

> If you are versed in or well versed in something, you know a lot about it.
>
> - She was well versed in Latin and Greek
> - Page is well versed in many styles of jazz. [+ in]

(Collins Dictionary)